# Best practice to insure the connection and response from external API results

Tags: python, django, api, transactions

I have this code in `python` (using `django` framework) that connects to an external `API` and update some values in that service. Each step depends on the previous step (for step 2 to work step 1 must return True and so forth that include a valid connection to the `API`). How can I insure that all of these steps takes place at the same time and if a single step fails how can I rollback and run all them at once in another try. here is the code. note that each class method do something in that external service.

```
# 1. add new value to account
if cls.add_balance(subscription_code, increase_amount):
# 2. set new base balance
if cls.set_topup_reset_action(
        subscription_code,
        new_base_balance,
):
    # 3. renew filters
    new_base_balance_20_percent = math.floor((Decimal(
        new_base_balance) * Decimal(20)) / Decimal(100))
    if cls.set_filter_80_percent(
            subscription_code,
            new_base_balance_20_percent,
    ) and cls.set_filter_100_percent(
        subscription_code,
    ):
        # 4. renew thresholds
        if cls.set_threshold_profile_80_percent(
                subscription_code,
        ) and cls.set_threshold_profile_100_percent(
            subscription_code,
        ):
            return True
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the atomicity of a transaction, the state of data should be stored before starting the execution of the atomic block. In the event of failure, we'll have to revert the data to the same state.

In this scenario, check if you can use the external api to fetch the existing values before starting the 4 steps. And if there is a provision to reset it back. Then store the values temporarily and revert if one of the steps fails.

Or try to deduce the changes that occur with the call of the external api and if you can revert it with some other way. With the external api being a black box and called in each step, it is not possible to ensure the transaction to be atomic.

If all four steps are calling the same api, then calculate all the parameters of the external api call in a single transaction and call the api only once.